# Find url with base folder and remove extension

Tags: php

How we get below URL from browser without extension:

Current URL

```
http://www.test.com/content/content-child/content-post.shtml
```

Expected URL

```
http://www.test.com/content/content-child/content-post
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear ! Please ask clearly what you wanna accomplish ! And attach some code here what you've tried.

Comment: Is this a WP question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have achieved this.